# Understanding JSF Process Flow

Tags: jsf, logging

I am currently studying the internal working of JSF. To aid this I would like to enable TRACE or DEBUG logs of all javax.faces classes. How can I do this? Can such a mechanism be done for other such frameworks too?

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks Balusc! This is really helpful and I am just going through your other tutorials. Wonderful!

Comment: BalusC is the author of the blog, I'm just pasting the link (and I'm not him :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `[jdk_install_dir]/jre/lib/logging.properties` file, scroll to the bottom and edit the following line near the bottom

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
```

into

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

and add the following two lines to the very bottom

```
javax.faces.level = ALL
com.sun.faces.level = ALL
```

The first turns all logging for JSF API and the second for the JSF impl, assuming that you're using Mojarra.